# Prolog: apply predicate to all list elements and sum results

Tags: list, prolog

I have a certain list which is generated from a predicate and looks like this:

```
[a, b, c]
```

I also have a following predicate `p/3` that could be applied to each element of my list:

```
?- p(a, NewList, Number).
```

and it will return:

```
NewList = [c, d],
Number = 2.
```

where **NewList** is a newly generated list from **a** element, and Number is the NewList length.

**Problem**:

I want to apply the `p/3` predicate to all elements, and get

1. one list which consists of all elements from all NewLists aka all NewLists appended together
2. and the sum of all Numbers.

I tried to do it like this:

```
loop_list([Element|[]], NewList, Number) :-
    p(Element, NewList, Number).
loop_list([Head|Tail], [Tmp|NewList], Number) :-
    loop_list(Tail, Tmp, Number).
```

but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is often better to separate your concerns, and solve one task at once. You can use [**`maplist/4`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/4) here to call the predicate over all the elements in the list. This will then unify the third and the fourth element with the results of `p/3`.

Next we can make use of [**`append/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) to append lists together, and [**`sumlist/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sum_list/2) to sum the elements of a list together.

We thus can implement this as:

```
loop_list(Ls, Xs, Sum) :-
    maplist(p, Ls, Xss, Items),
    append(Xss, Xs),
    sumlist(Items, Sum).
```